# How to show next and prev navigation in a folder in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I need to create a previous and next navigation in one folder using a structure like page 1 page 2 etc
My current not-working code is the following:

```
<?php 
    $search_dir = "gallery";
    $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
    sort($images);
    $current = 2;
    $prev_img = $images[$current - 1];
    $next_img = $images[$current + 1];
    // Image selection and display:

    //display first image
    if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
        $img = $images[0]; // first image 
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $prev_img; ?>">Previous</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $next_img; ?>">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
        <figure><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img; ?>"></figure>
    <?php 
        } else {
      echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you mean `page Navigations` or 'folder'

Comment: It's a gallery I got N photos.jpg in the folder and a gallery.php who shows one photo, I would to show the other photos using a navigation prev and next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit in hurry please try this code i have made some correction please look into the code, try to understand.

```
<?php 
    $search_dir = "gallery";
    $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
    sort($images);
    if(isset($_REQUEST['image_no']))
    {
        $image_no = $_REQUEST['image_no'];    
    }
    else
    {
        $image_no = 2;
    }

    $prev_img = ($image_no == 0)?(count($images)-1):($image_no -1);
    $next_img = ($image_no == count($images)-1)?0:($image_no + 1);
    // Image selection and display:

    //display first image
    if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
        $img = $images[$image_no]; // first image 
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?image_no=<?php echo $prev_img; ?>">Previous</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.php?image_no=<?php echo $next_img; ?>">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
        <figure><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="<?php echo $img; ?>"></figure>
    <?php 
        } else {
      echo 'error';
    }
?>
```

Comment: It returns: Notice: Undefined index: image_no in /var/www/html/gallery.php on line 43 which is: if($_REQUEST['image_no']!='')

Comment: There is an option for php.ini google it how to paas request variable...or set gallery.php?image_no= in ur default ur to check it

Comment: changed to gallery.php?image_no but it shows me the same error

Comment: What is ur file name...my file name was gallery.php so keept it in my code and in url

Comment: there is a tick option in my answer at the left side, if this help you can tick it, so it can help other also